# Running water in master shower causes guest bathtub spigot to drip

Tags: water, shower, bathtub

If this sounds familiar, I deleted my previous question cause I have more info that changes the facts.

I noticed that my son's guest bathroom tub had a little water around the drain after I took a shower. Last night, he ran the shower for a while and then noticed the guest bathtub spigot started a slow drip. What would cause that?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this with washer less faucets. The pressure drop causes them to drip especially if they are older. A set of new seals and possibly springs may tighten it enough to stop the drip, The big box stores Cary kits with different sizes some times they are color coded to size, there are at least 3 different sizes that I can remember, or you could pull the cartridge and take it with you to the store to make sure to get the correct size
[here is a sample of what I think you need](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/151625827758?lpid=82&chn=ps&ul_ref=http%253A%252F%252Frover.ebay.com%252Frover%252F1%252F711-117182-37290-0%252F2%253Fmtid%253D1588%2526kwid%253D1%2526crlp%253D53601919689_324272%2526itemid%253D151625827758%2526targetid%253D154774675929%2526rpc%253D0.05%2526rpc_upld_id%253D70664%2526device%253Dm%2526mpre%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.ebay.com%25252Fulk%25252Fitm%25252Flike%25252F151625827758%25253Flpid%25253D82%252526chn%25253Dps%2526adtype%253Dpla%2526googleloc%253D9033087%2526poi%253D9033033%2526campaignid%253D239125209%2526adgroupid%253D14978428809%2526rlsatarget%253Dpla-154774675929%2526gclid%253DCIG5y-WQ7swCFUmRfgodVWMJ5Q%2526srcrot%253D711-117182-37290-0%2526rvr_id%253D1033859863964&ul_noapp=true).

Comment: Is there an easy way to tell if this is washerless? It's a Peerless round, single handle with two screws on the trim plate around it. So I can take the handle and the trim plate off.

Comment: Most all single handles are warsherless.